# BufferedWriter works on Windows but not Mac

Tags: java, macos, io

So I am using this method to write to a file, it works totally fine on windows but when run on mac it creates the files but they are empty.

```
public static void writeLinesToTextFile(String path, String[] lines) {
File file = new File(r + path);
if (!file.exists()) {
    try {
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    BufferedWriter bw;

    try {

        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file.getPath()));
        file.delete();
        file.createNewFile();

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            //System.out.println(lines[i]);
            bw.write(lines[i]);
            bw.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I know the data is right because it prints correctly.
Thanks for any help, this has really been tripping me out.

Comment: Instead of `bw.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"))`, you could use `bw.newLine()`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine--

Comment: FYI, I've edited my answer to add an explanation of this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't delete the `file` after creating a `BufferedWriter`. In Linux, every file has a unique file handle, so deleting and recreating a file with the same path creates 2 different file handles. I don't know what Windows does as I don't consider it a real OS, but from your post, it appears that it uses the same file handle.